# Different Subdomains directing to the same Apache Virtual Host?

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have two subdomains, each register with my dns registrar to point to my VPS ip address. Pinging both resolve fine. I have two Virtual Host configurations for two sites but the problem is that both subdomains redirect to the same page. I am confused and must be missing something within Apache which is causing this strange occurrence.

My DNS settings are set to A records to the ip of my VPS. Is this correct? I dont believe I need CNAMEs.

> ```
> <VirtualHost *>   
>
> ServerName phpmyadmin.<mydomain>.com             
>
> DocumentRoot "/srv/www/phpmyadmin"                                                                                                                                    
>
> <Directory "/srv/www/phpmyadmin">                                                                   
> allow from all                                                                                      
> Options +Indexes +Includes +ExecCGI                                                                 
> </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                        
> </VirtualHost>   
>
> <VirtualHost *>                                                                                     
> ServerName panel.<mydomain>.com                                                                        
> DocumentRoot "/srv/www/repo_project"               
>
>
> WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/repo_project/django.wsgi     
>
>
> <Directory "/srv/www/repo_project">              
>
> allow from all                                                                                      
> Options +Indexes +Includes +ExecCGI                                                                 
> </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                       
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Comment: Sorry for ask but: you reload apache afther the changes you made? Also, are you sure apache is reading this file?

Comment: Yes and its driving me mad. /etc/inid.d/apache2 restart

Comment: You say both subdomains redirect to the same page. Is this page the same as one of the two above or is a completely different page?

Comment: Both redirect to my index page for PhpMyAdmin which is installed under one of the VirtualHost root directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare `NameVirtualHost *` just above these `Virtual Host` declarations?

See `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html`

Comment: This was it. I dont understand this REQUIRED directive is not in Debians apache.conf when it already has entries in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. 

Thanks, Devin (Ill search for you on Stack overflow to upvote you there, Im too new here :)